# Where can I find vhost configuration for symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

I want to access my site via testing.dev instead of localhost:8000.
How can I achieve this?

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Websites/test"
    ServerName www.testing.dev
    ServerAlias testing.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I googled the problem, but they all speak of a httpd-vhost.conf file, but I don't seem to have one in my project.

Where / how can I find it? FYI, I'm using the built in webserver (bin/console server:run)

**Tried this already**

- I found a httpd-vhost.conf in my xampp folder (don't use xampp tho)

Comment: "bin/console server:run testing.dev" will sort of do what you want.  You will need to have testing.dev defined in your hosts file.  The vhost file is part of apache and has no relation to the symfony server:run command.

Comment: @Cerad does not work unfortunately

Comment: Equally unfortunate are phrases such as "does not work"

Comment: @Cerad, what did you expect to get as an answer then?

Comment: @Refilon  https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html